# call mysql store procedure from php with variable table and more param

Tags: php, mysql

this is is my problem: I want to put this query into store procedure:

select col1,col2 from var1 where site_cluster = var2;

I create the procedure like this:

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists get_register$$
CREATE procedure get_registers(IN var1 VARCHAR(15),IN var2 VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
DECLARE l_sql_stmt varchar (100);
SET @l_sql_stmt = CONCAT('SELECT col1,col2 from ',var1," where site_cluster='",var2,"'");
SELECT @l_sql_stmt;
prepare stmt from @l_sql_stmt;
execute stmt; 
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

And from php I do:

```
###connection to db is defined in other class####
$query = "call get_registers('var1','var2')"; 
    if($result = $this->connection->query($query)){
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
            $register_array[$row['col1']]['col2']=$row['col1'];
            $register_array[$row['col1']]['col2']=$row['col2'];
        }
        return $register_array;
    }
```

So ...
while executing
call get_enbs('var1','var2');
it is working from mysql cli , i can not get it working from php.
any ideas would be wellcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Try ```SELECT get_registers('var1','var2');```

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple reasons why 'call' does not work.

Most common is you forgot to put multi-statement support into your mysql_connect function . like this :

$this->connection = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->passw,false,65536);

this is directly from call documentation mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/call.html

> This is because each CALL returns a result to indicate the call status, in addition to any result sets that might be returned by statements executed within the procedure

you can also try

Exec get_registers('var1','var2')

instead if the above does not work.